# Can an Ajax Modal window access Parent window PHP data?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have `parent.php` that pops up an exit pop up modal window by using this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( "#modal-layer" ).load( "/exit.php" );
</script>
```

`parent.php` has some php data such as:

`$name= "Abraham";`

While `exit.php` has the following code:

`Hello, <?php echo $name; ?>!`

But the result is blank, because `$name` doesn't get through the Ajax window.

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Either save the name in a cookie or a session, or use `$( "#modal-layer" ).load( "/exit.php?name=<?=$name?>" );`, and in `exit.php`, do `Hello, <?php echo $_GET['name']; ?>!` (Using this data without any validation might be dangerous)

Comment: @blex the GET is a nice option, though how can I make it work when the name is two words separated by space? `/exit.php?name=Abraham Linocln`  won't work

Comment: Might be a good case for session data

Comment: I think session might be an overkill in this case

Answer (score 1):

cheap and dirty, add the name to the query string of the php file call

```
$( "#modal-layer" ).load( "/exit.php?name=<?php echo urlencode($name); ?>" );
```

then in exit.php

```
Hello, <?php echo urldecode($_GET['name']); ?>!
```

the alternative:

```
$( "#modal-layer" ).load( "/exit.php", { "name": <?php echo $name); ?>} );
```

Comment: what if the name contains two words seperated by space?

Comment: What is the alternative? It doesn't look like a PHP code, so how can it effect the PHP data of the ajax window?